# Expo init from template alternative with npx

Tags: react-native, expo

According to a template example
https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/realm/using-expo-realm-expo-dev-client/
I would initialize this specific react native expo template like so:

```
npx expo-cli init ReactRealmJSTemplateApp -t @realm/expo-template-js
```

This gives me the error:
$ expo init is not supported in the local CLI, please use npx create-expo-app instead

I then run:

```
npx create-expo-app ReactRealmJSTemplateApp -t @realm/expo-template-js
```

It appears not to read the template and gives me the error:
Emitted 'error' event on ReadStream instance at...
Any idea how I can load a template with the npx create-expo-app

Answer (score 0):

First: Open cmd and npx create-expo-app --template

Second: Select 1 template from the list of available templates

Three: your project's name

See more: https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-project/